# Invoke java class static initialization via VM option

Tags: java, jvm, static-initialization

Is there any way to force static initialization of some class `B` before entering the `main()` method of class `A`, without changing class `A`, using only VM options?

Comment: Explain better what you're trying to achieve. There's no VM option for that (what would be the use?) though.

Comment: I just wonder if there is a way to do so.

Comment: No, there's a reason why you wonder that. Tell us the reason.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could create a class that initializes other classes and then calls the real main method, e.g:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    Class<?> mainClass = Class.forName(System.getProperty("mainClass"));

    for (String className : System.getProperty("initClasses").split(";")) {
        Class.forName(className);
    }

    Method main = mainClass.getMethod("main", String[].class);
    main.invoke(null, new Object[] { args });
}
```

Then you would start the application with that class as the main class and specify the real main class and the classes to be initialized via properties.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not aware of any way to do it without code. In code it's easy of course.

```
public class C {
   static {
      // Fetch and throw away an instance of B to make sure it is loaded
      B.getInstance();
   }

   static void main(String[] args) {
      // Do stuff, B is initialized
      A.main(args);
   }
}
```

In fact you could just do

```
public class C {
   static void main(String[] args) {
      B.getInstance();
      A.main(args);
   }
}
```

Your request doesn't make a lot of sense though. Ask a question about the problem you are trying to solve by doing this and you will hopefully get a much more useful answer.

Comment: Thanks for reply. I didn't consider the option to use other class so it might be helpful.